# How to increase connectionlimit for aws lambda with js sdk

Tags: javascript, lambda, aws-lambda

Currently I am only able to have max **50** concurrent execution of lambda function. Is it because I have to set up **ConnectionLimit**.

With aws .net skd I can set it up by:

```
new AmazonLambdaClient(new AmazonLambdaConfig
    {
        ConnectionLimit = 200,
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2
    });
```

/// here is the code I used to invoke lambda

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

function fireLambda(){
    var lambdaParams = {
        FunctionName: "testLambda", 
        InvocationType: "RequestResponse", 
        LogType: "Tail", 
        Payload: '{"msgCount": 888}'
       };

   lambda.invoke(lambdaParams, function(err, data) {
         if (err){
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
         }else{
            console.log(data);           // successful response
         }

         fireLambda();
       });
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let maxCount = event.maxConcurrentCount || 50;

    setTimeout(() => {
        process.exit(1);
    }, 8000);
    while(maxCount > 0)
    {
        maxCount--;
        fireLambda();
    }
};
```

Also, this Lambda has max concurrent limit set to **300**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at: [AWSjavascriptSDKdoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#putFunctionConcurrency-property)

Specifically the function `putFunctionConcurrency` which wants the parameters:

```
- FunctionName = name of the function you are setting concurrent execution limits on.
- ReservedConcurrentExecutions = concurrent execution limit number
```

Comment: Hi Pietro, thanks for the tips. I already set the concurrent limit to 200 on aws dashboard before doing the test run.